# Export FBX to Unreal

Tags: export, subdivision-surface, .fbx, unreal-engine

I have created a couple of models (with materials applied to them) that I have applied subdivision surface in adaptive mode. Some of them in Catmull-Clark mode and some other to Simple mode.
I want to import my models into the Unreal Engine, and I am wondering which is the best way to maintain the subdivision. 
There are options under the Geometry sector with Smoothing (Normals Only, Face, Edge), Export Subdivision Surface, Apply Modifiers etc.
Additionally, should I export my models as high poly or as low poly? I will apply later in Unreal Engine a specific modifier like in Blender? Or there is not this option?

[image]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your game. although unreal is good at handling high poly assets if you do LOD.
The smoothing option is for smooth shading.

My recommendation would be to make range of tris budget count for assets (like up to 2k tris for none important and up to 12k tris for important, although if its a vr game you can go higher it's up to you and your target hardware and frame rate)

Comment: It is a an environment scene with a couple of buildings, streets and props, for my Portfolio. No VR.

Comment: if it's a Portfolio scene then keep them as good looking as you can with in reason so you could at least hit 30 fps for showcasing it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't feel that you give me an answer! I want also to have the best result, for this reason, I am asking how I will achieve it!